# Criar uma janela resizable

Tags: c++, winapi

Olá, eu fui consegui criar uma janela de consola que não mostra as barras de scroll:

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
int columns, rows;
COORD size;
COORD BufSize;

while(TRUE) {
    size = GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    columns = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
    rows = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;

    BufSize.X = columns;
    BufSize.Y = rows;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BufSize);
    sleep(5);
}
```

No entanto, a consola criada por este código não permite que nós aumentemos de tamanho a consola, só dá para reduzir de tamanho. Para isso mudei as seguintes linhas de código:

```
columns = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
rows = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;
```

Para:

```
columns = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 2;
rows = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 2;
```

Desta maneira, com algum esforço, já dá para aumentar o tamanho da consola. No entanto, desta maneira também reaparecem as barras de scroll, algo que gostaria que não aparecessem. Alguém sabe alguma solução de como eu adaptaria o código acima para que não aparecessem as barras de scroll, mantendo a janela da consola totalmente *resizable*?

Comment: A barra de scroll é exibida quando o tamanho do buffer é maior que o tamanho da janela.

Comment: @CypherPotato Sim, estou ciente desse facto, razão pela qual cheguei aos resultados colocados na questão acima.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente adicionar a seguinte função ao seu projeto:

```
void remove_scrollbar(){

    HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(handle, &info);
    COORD new_size = 
    {
        csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1,
        csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1
    };
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(handle, new_size);
}
```